# Subscribe to a subject only fired once

Tags: angular, rxjs, subject

I created a service in order to get datas from an API and use a Subject to get theses datas from my component (LoadTenants is called at the app initialization):

The service :

```
@Injectable()
 export class TenantService{
  public tenants;
  private tenantSubject = new Subject<any>();

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

LoadTenants() {
    this.http.get(TENANT_URL).subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.tenants = data;
        this.setTenants();
    });
}

setTenants() {
    this.tenantSubject.next(this.tenants);
}

getTenants(): Observable<any> {
    return this.tenantSubject.asObservable();
}

getSyncTenants() {
    return this.tenants;
}
}
```

The component :

```
public tenant;
subsciption: Subscription;

constructor(private tenantService: TenantService) { }

ngOnInit() {
        this.subsciption = this.tenantService.getTenants().subscribe((datas) => {
            this.tenant = datas;
        },
            error => console.log('Error : ', error)
        );
    }
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subsciption.unsubscribe();
}
```

Everything is working fine on the first load, but if I navigate to an other component and come back to this one, the subscription is not fired resulting on void datas in my template.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to get Latest Value Then Use BehaviorSubject

BehaviorSubject will directly emit the current value to the subscriber

```
 @Injectable()
     export class TenantService{
      public tenants;
      private tenantSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>();

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    LoadTenants() {
        this.http.get(TENANT_URL).subscribe((data: any) => {
            this.tenants = data;
            this.setTenants();
        });
    }
    setTenants() {
      this.tenantSubject.next(this.tenants);
    }

   getTenants(): Observable<any> {
      return this.tenantSubject.asObservable();
   }

   getSyncTenants() {
      return this.tenants;
   }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Chellapan, it works with private tenantSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(0) even if I'm not sure to understand why and what is going on there.

Comment: The problem is a subject does not store values. You use next on the subject and every subscriber gets the emitted value. But you do this just once when your application starts. When you navigate back subscription is triggered again but your subject doesn't emit anything, so nothing happens. A Behavoir subject stores the latest value and every new subscriber gets immediately the latest value emitted.